# How do I enter xx:xx in a 24-hour format without the ":" giving errors?

Tags: java

I have to convert a 24 hour clock into minutes in this format, while allowing the user to enter whatever time they want. So far my code only allows them to enter the XX:XX as long as there is a space in between the two XX's, instead of the Colon. I have tried using a delimiter but that just cuts of the last two XX's which will act as the minutes.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TaskA {

    ///import the tools necessary i.e java.util.* and Scanner console. I have also used a delimiter to render the ":" as not being read.

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(":");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ///This is how I will define the time. using both hours and minutes for the console.

     int hours;
     int minutes;
     int total_mins;

    ///Here I have written how the question will come out and what the user will have to enter.

        System.out.print("Specify time (HH:MM) :   ");

    /// Here I have the hours and minutes being inputed, as well as a draft on the final statement.

        hours = console.nextInt();
        minutes = console.nextInt();

    ///This is the mathematical equation for total minutes. 

        total_mins = (hours * 60) + minutes;

    ///final statement.

        System.out.print(hours + ":" + minutes + " = " + total_mins + " Mins !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Split the string on the delimiter and you will have the two halves

Comment: Have you seen my answer? It seems your code should work as is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would treat it as a string, and then split it.

```
 String line = console.nextLine();
 hours = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[0]);
 minutes = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been stressing about this for almost a week now and it's relieving to see it solved so easy.

Comment: It would be better to cache the splitted string: `String[] splitParts = console.nextLine().split(":"); if (splitParts.length >= 2) { hours = Integer.parseInt(splitParts[0]); minutes = Integer.parseInt(splitParts[1]); } else { /* Handle invalid input */ }`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done:

```
String[] splitParts = console.nextLine().split(":");
if (splitParts.length >= 2)
    try
    {
        hours = Integer.parseInt(splitParts[0]);
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(splitParts[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.err.println("The entered numbers were of invalid format!");
    }
else
{
    System.err.println("Please enter a input of format ##:##!");
}
```

This code handles the dangers of user input as well, as you can see.